# Imported XML occupying multiple rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, xml

I want to import an XML file into an Excel sheet in order to perform operations.

When I import the XML file I get the following structure:

[image: XML file for Excel]

As you can see, all variables are on different lines.

Here is the structure of the file

```
<FIELD Name="RSECTO" Description="Resectorisation indicator" MinCol="0" MaxCol="47" CollapseVert="true" PackHoriz="true">
    <FORMAT_FUNC>
        <FMT>fmt:lz_resecto(.flight_co,\"\216\")</FMT>
        <FCLR>clr:fg_constant(C_Resectorisation)</FCLR>
        <SENS>sens:constant(true)</SENS>
        <VIS>vis:constant(true)</VIS>
        </FORMAT_FUNC>
</FIELD>
```

How can I make excel put the data into one row?

Comment: Just opening the XML file and I choose the option "Open as an xml table" (translating from french) and there is no schema reference, so Excel made one.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks for editing, it's better now

Comment: Do you want the whole content of your file in one row, or just the variables?

Comment: In one row : one row for une node in the xml file